# Расширение Chrome на JavaScript. Открыть вкладку с сайтом и получить его "document"

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Задача: 
Расширение chrome, при нажатии на которое появляется страничка с кнопкой и при нажатии на эту кнопку открывается конкретный сайт. И с этим сайтом я хочу работать - кликать на кнопки и тд.

Всё получилось, кроме одного: нужен доступ к "document" сайта и я не могу его получить.

Напишите пожалуйста конкретный код, а не просто на словах. Уже третий день гуглю проблему - перепробовал десятки кусков кода - ничего не работает.

Файл manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": ["activeTab"],

    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Файл popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
      <button id="click-this">Run script</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Файл index.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    document.getElementById("click-this").addEventListener("click", main);
});

function main()
{
    var ref = 'https://vk.com/my_id';
    // тут всё ок, вкладка открывается
    var win = window.open(ref);
    // 5 секунд ждать, чтобы сайт успел загрузиться
    sleep(5);
    // не работает, как будто здесь document не того сайта что открылся
    win.document.getElementById('profile_edit_act').click();
}

function sleep(seconds)
{
    var ms = seconds * 1000;
    ms += new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date() < ms){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расширения явным образом не имеют доступа к элементам сайта, однако дают возможность  сделать на стороне страницы, вставив туда необходимые скрипты:

---

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.1",
  "name": "stackoverflow",

  "permissions": ["activeTab","tabs", "*://vk.com/*"],
  "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://vk.com/*"],
      "js": ["inject.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "vk.js"
  ]
}
```

---

`index.js`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementById("click-this").addEventListener("click", main);
});

function main(){
    window.open('https://vk.com/my_id');
}
```

---

`inject.js`

```
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', chrome.extension.getURL('vk.js'));
node.appendChild(script);
```

---

`vk.js`

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert(document.querySelector('.page_name').innerHTML);
}, 1000);
```

---

PS: `popup.html` я не менял